# Pandas- Finding the first time a value changes in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
account    date
  A        0812
  A        0812
  A        0812
  A        0823
  A        0823
  B        0723
  B        0730
  B        0730
  B        0801
  B        0801
  B        0801
```

I want to get the 'date' value for the first time the value changes per account. So the output I'm looking for is this:

```
account   date
  A       0823
  B       0730
```

I have tried to do a dense rank groupby function and filter by rank equaling 1.

***df.groupby('account')['date'].rank(method='dense')*** but the output keeps the same rank for the same value, which does not work. 'first' and 'last' ranks don't seem to be working either.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) first and then get second value per group, by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['account','date'])

df1 = df1[df1.groupby('account').cumcount().eq(1)]
print (df1)
  account  date
3       A   823
6       B   730
```

Or by [`GroupBy.nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['account','date'])

df1 = df1.groupby('account', as_index=False).nth(1)
print (df1)
  account  date
3       A   823
6       B   730
```